# How to convert array Type InetAddress into String[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, inetaddress

How to convert array Type InetAddress

```
InetAddress[] inetAddress
```

into String Array as in given below format !!

```
String[] addrSplit = ??
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You get answers faster, and the answers tend to be of better quality, when you show your best failed attempt at doing whatever is you are trying to do. This is because your code may require a tiny correction, while you already understand the overwhelming majority of it.

Answer (score 1):

won't

```
String[] addrSplit = new String[inetAddress.length];
for (int i = 0; i < addrSplit.length; i++) {
    addrSplit[i] = inetAddress[i].toString();
}
```

work?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the `InetAddress` array and `InetAddress#getCanonicalHostName()` will return [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) address in `String` if you need or, `InetAddress#getHostName()`  which return the host name for this IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over inetaddress

```
   InetAddress[] inetAddress;
      String[] data= new String[inetAddress.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < inetAddress.length; i++) {
         data[i]=inetAddress[i].getHostAddress();
      }
```

Comment: Assigning a `InetAddress` to a `String` won't compile.

Comment: Put it in your IDE and try to compile it. `data[i]=inetAddress[i];` will not work. because you are trying to assign an `InetAdress` to a `String`, but you're only allowed to assign a `String` to a `String` in Java.

Comment: @jlordo did you see this line? data[i]=inetAddress[i].getHostAddress();

Comment: In the future I recommend to always code in your IDE and copy/paste it here. You'll have nice formatting by default and the posted code won't have compiler errors. I removed my -1, as the error is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String[] addrSplit = new String[inetAddress.length];
for (int i = 0; i < addrSplit.length; i++) {
  addrSplit[i] = inetAddress[i].toString();
}
```